# Java - File getFreeSpace difference between Mac and Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, java-io

I am trying to get the free space from my NAS, but Mac and Windows return different values.
I use java.io.File and the method getFreeSpace.

Mac outcome, which is ***incorrect***:

39.13465499... GB

Windows outcome, which is ***correct***:

4134.864555... GB

My code:

```
    private static String multiMediaFolder;
    private static long freeDiskSpace;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X")){
        multiMediaFolder = "/Volumes/Multimedia/movies/HD";
    } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").substring(0, 7).equals("Windows")){
        multiMediaFolder = "\\\\QNAP\\Multimedia\\movies\\HD";
    }

    freeDiskSpace = new File(multiMediaFolder).getFreeSpace();
    double sizeInGigaByte = (double) freeDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024; 

    System.out.println(sizeInGigaByte);
 }
```

The paths are different, but point at the same folder. Why is the Mac version way different than the Windows version?

Comment: Looks like the difference between (1024*1024*1024) = 1 GB, and (1000*1000*1000) = 1 GB

Comment: That seems like a painfully obvious bug to leave in some operating system code...

Comment: It's not really a bug. Apple has documentation explaining why base 10 was chosen: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2419

Comment: Also, just curious, what do Finder/Windows Explorer report for the size of that folder?

Comment: I just found a link about a known bug with Samba (smb) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7036346. Since my NAS has a size of 8TB, smb can't handle this. So it does not work on a Mac, but on Windows it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my answer. There are two differences, like we saw in my post above me.

Linux returns 4326416688 <- which are kilobytes.

Mac (just like linux) returns 4326416688 <- which are kilobytes too.

Windows returns a bigger number 4429798060032 <- which are bytes.

This explains why the Windows value was correct.

The code that I am going to use now:

```
private static String multiMediaFolder;
private static long freeDiskSpace;
private static double sizeInGigaByte;


public static void main(String[] args) {

   if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X")){
       multiMediaFolder = "/Volumes/Multimedia/movies/HD";
       freeDiskSpace = new File(multiMediaFolder).getFreeSpace();
       sizeInGigaByte = (double) freeDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024;
   } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").substring(0, 7).equals("Windows")){
       multiMediaFolder = "\\\\QNAP\\Multimedia\\movies\\HD";
       freeDiskSpace = new File(multiMediaFolder).getFreeSpace();
       sizeInGigaByte = (double) freeDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
   }

   System.out.println(sizeInGigaByte);
}
```